# Execute oAuth 1.0 API in Android

Tags: android, oauth, android-volley

> Hi i worked with oAuth 1.0 API. Whenever i execute it with Postman it respond with success but when i execute it in Android it will return error Authentication fail.
>   For execute API i used volley.
>   I have information of

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Signature Method (HMAC-SHA1)
- Timestamp
- Nonce
- Version (1.0)

> I have passed this in information in postman's Authorization section and it returns success result. Now i needed to pass this information to Volley Request but it returns authentication failed error every time.
>   For authentication i create string with oAuth details and passed it to header.

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        final String ts = tsLong.toString();

        String value = "OAuth " + "oauth_consumer_key" + "=\"OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY\","
                + "oauth_signature_method" + "=\"" + "HMAC-SHA1" + "\","
                + "oauth_timestamp" + "=\"" + ts + "\","
                + "oauth_nonce" + "=\"" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\","
                + "oauth_version" + "=\"" + "1.0" + "\","
                + "oauth_signature" + "=\"" + OAUTH_SIGNATURE + "\"";
        headers.put("Authorization", value);
```

> **OAUTH_SIGNATURE**  is auto-generate by Postman.But in android i don't know about how to generate it.
>   After googling i got method for generate oAuth signature.

```
public static String hmacDigest(String msg, String keyString, String algo) {
    String digest = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), algo);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algo);
        mac.init(key);
        byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("ASCII"));
        StringBuffer hash = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hash.append('0');
            }
            hash.append(hex);
        }
        digest = hash.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return digest;
}
```

> Here i know only parameter is algo which is **HmacSHA1**. But there is msg & key which i don't have.
>   If i selected wrong way to get it then suggest me a right way to get it.

So,please help me to get oAuth 1.0 API execute.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Copy the authorization header from Postman and put it on Authorization header of Volley (make sure you dont have space) .e.g My Config.java contains :

```
public static final String headerData = "your_auth_data_from_postman";
public static final String TWITTER_SEARCH_URL = "url_for_get_or_post";
```

Then on volley do this

```
 @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Authorization", Config.headerData);
            return params;
        }
```

Then on volley just fill in Authorization header with headerData. I was able to get json data from Twitter using this. Let me know if this helps!